# C# WPF Save Screenshot

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

When I Call SaveImageCommandExecute, it gives me a error and I don't understand it. Can someone explain it? Thanks Alot :).

**Error:**
https://pastebin.com/8RnvKs95

**Code:**

```
private void SaveImageCommandExecute()
    {
        string pathToFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
        ApplicationViewModel ApplicationVM = System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources["MainViewModel"] as ApplicationViewModel;

        string filePath;
        string fullPath;
        using (FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            dlg.Description = "Select folder";
            dlg.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
            dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = dlg.SelectedPath;
                fullPath = filePath + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss_dd-MM-yyyy") + ".jpeg";
                camera.SaveThermalImage(@"C:\programs\file.jpeg");
            }
        }

    }
```

BTW I am using a Workswell WIC SDK.

Comment: Put a try-catch block and check the `InnerException` property for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you generate the `fullPath` but don't use it. You use the hardcoded `C:\programs\file.jpeg` instead. That folder might not exist. Here it is with that one line edited.

```
private void SaveImageCommandExecute()
{
    string pathToFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
    ApplicationViewModel ApplicationVM = System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources["MainViewModel"] as ApplicationViewModel;

    string filePath;
    string fullPath;
    using (FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        dlg.Description = "Select folder";
        dlg.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
        dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filePath = dlg.SelectedPath;
            fullPath = filePath + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss_dd-MM-yyyy") + ".jpeg";
            camera.SaveThermalImage(fullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I don't know how `camera.SaveThermalImage` works, there could also be an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Progams won't exist.

You're presumably thinking of c:\Program Files.

Users will almost certainly not be able to write to folders under c:\program files and so even if you "corrected" this line will therefore fail:

```
camera.SaveThermalImage(@"C:\program files\file.jpeg");
```

As it turns out, allowing people to write to where your programs are opens up a security hole.
Seeing as how it's in the user's context that malware often tries to do it's mal-ness.

This issue was resolved some years back and you've not been able to just save files to this location since win 7 iirc.

This is admittedly counter intuitive but easily proved.

Run notepad.

File > Save

Try and save blaa.txt into c:\program files and see what happens.

[image: You can't write there]

You should instead write to somewhere like commondocuments as your file picker uses or appdata.

There is another issue to beware of with file pickers.

I forget how the winforms dialog works exactly.
I guess this probably allows the user to pick a different folder than you're expecting though.
As a result, it's common to write custom UI for such purposes - which doesn't allow folder change.